# Android Text in layout damaged (v 2.3)

Tags: android, layout

i want to display some text informations in frame layout, on android devices with version > 2.3 is everything displayed correctly, but on devices with android 2.3 is text damaged (see attached screen). (No error, no )

I would like to ask, what can causing this issue and how to solve.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Source of framelaout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- CAR CLASS TV -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carClassTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Typ automobilu: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carClassTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Osobní auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- MANUFACTURER TV -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturerTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Výrobce: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturerTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wolkswagen"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<!-- CAR TYPE TV -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carTypeTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Typ: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carTypeTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PASSAT"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR TYPE COLOR -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carColorTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Barva: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carColorTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Modrá tmavá"
    android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR SERIAL NUMBER -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carSerialNumberTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Výrobní číslo: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carSerialNumberTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WVWZZZ3BZ2E409524"
    android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<!-- CAR ENGINE -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carEngineNumberTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Motor: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carEngineNumberTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WVWZZZ3"
    android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR MANUFACTURE DATE -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carManufacturedTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rok výroby: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carManufacturedTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2002"
    android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR STOLEN DATE -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carStolenDateTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Odcizeno: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carStolenDateTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="13.3.2013"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp" />


<!-- DETAIL BUTTON -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submiBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="Zobrazit záznam na webu PČR"
    android:textColor="@color/lighter_blue"
    android:onClick="visitWebsite"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a FrameLayout for layouts like this. All childs inside a FrameLayout will be positioned in the upper left corner. So, all TextViews are overlapped and that's why you get this output.
The only way to position Views in a FrameLayout is the `layout_gravity` tag.

Try a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout instead.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it displayed correctly on Android > 2.3 ? Is there some version difference in layout render or something else?

Comment: To be honest I dont know... Everytime I tried to build a layout like yours with a FrameLayout, lead to the same result you are getting right now.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `TextViews` with `LinerLayout` with orientation `vertical`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carClassTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Typ automobilu: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carClassTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Osobní auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- MANUFACTURER TV -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturerTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Výrobce: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturerTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wolkswagen"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<!-- CAR TYPE TV -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carTypeTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Typ: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carTypeTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PASSAT"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR TYPE COLOR -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carColorTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Barva: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carColorTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Modrá tmavá"
    android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR SERIAL NUMBER -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carSerialNumberTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Výrobní číslo: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carSerialNumberTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WVWZZZ3BZ2E409524"
    android:layout_marginTop="255dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<!-- CAR ENGINE -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carEngineNumberTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Motor: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carEngineNumberTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WVWZZZ3"
    android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR MANUFACTURE DATE -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carManufacturedTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rok výroby: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carManufacturedTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2002"
    android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />


<!-- CAR STOLEN DATE -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carStolenDateTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Odcizeno: "
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/carStolenDateTvValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="13.3.2013"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp" />


<!-- DETAIL BUTTON -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submiBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="Zobrazit záznam na webu PČR"
    android:textColor="@color/lighter_blue"
    android:onClick="visitWebsite"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout >
```